# Showing that an equation has a root in an interval

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

Show that the equation $x^4 - 7x^3 + 1 = 0$ has a root in the interval $[0,1]$.

How would I go about working this out in steps?

Comment: Did you try drawing a graph? The answer might be apparent

Comment: Note that $1^4-7\cdot 1^3+1\lt 0$ and that $0^4-7\cdot 0^3+1\gt 0$.

Comment: Try filling in $x=0$ and $x=1$ and use a continuity argument.

Comment: If I put 0 and 1 into the equation, with 0 I get an answer of 0 and 1 an answer of -5. What do I need to do next to complete the question?

Comment: @Stephen If you actually got $f(0)=0$, then you've have your root right there and there would be nothing else to do. But $f(0)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x^4-7x^3+1$. Note that $f(x)$ is a continuous function.

Since $$f(0)=0^4-7\cdot 0^3+1=1\gt 0$$
and 
$$f(1)=1^4-7\cdot 1^3+1=-5\lt 0,$$

there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that
$$f(\alpha)=0\ \ \text{and}\ \ 0\lt\alpha\lt 1$$ by the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

As said consider $$f(x)=x^4-7x^3+1$$ and by inspection you notice that $f(0)\times f(1)<0$; so there is **at least** a root between $0$ and $1$.

Look at the derivative $$f'(x)=4x^3-21x^2=x^2(4x-21)$$ It it positive if $x > \frac {21}4$. So, in the considered interval, there is only one root.